# Error in insert statement for HSQL DB

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hsqldb, spring-data-rest

I have Spring data rest application & for unit testing these services, I am using Spring Boot & HSQL in memory databse. But while inserting data into the HSQL table at runtime, I am getting an error. While other insert statements are working, I am getting this error only for 1 insert statement.

Error

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column count does not match in statement

Insert Statement in SQL file

```
Insert into countries (ID,COUNTRY,CODE) values (2,'UNITED STATES','US');
```

Note:- In the same application insert for other tables are working & retrieval of the data from the table is also successful.

Entity - Using this HSQL create the table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRIES")
public class Country implements Describable, Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CountriesSeq",sequenceName="SEQ_COUNTRIES")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "CountriesSeq")
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }   
}
```

Thanks

Comment: have you added any constraint on the table

Comment: No. If I execute the same statement on the actual database, it execute successfully.

Comment: so you are doing it through a JDBC call ??. I suppose in case of JDBC call you will need to include all the columns of the table in the statement. For the values you are not passing in the insert statement you can pass null 


For example Insert into countries (ID,COUNTRY,CODE, CONTINENT) values (2,'UNITED STATES','US', null);

Comment: If possible pass on your SQL schema for the tables and the code you have written. I may be able to test it and recreate the issue

Comment: tables are created by HSQL DB by using entities that i have. I have added the entity & SQL statement in the question. Other insert statement that i have in the application are working fine. JFYI i have tried passing null value for the id, as it is auto generated. but that didnt help

Comment: as you will understand I do not have access to your source to completely debug this. If you have simple project you can maybe share the source(complete project) through dropbox or github. I do not see any specific reason for this to fail. Only case would be if Entity created a separate column which is unknown to you.

Comment: And a question are you able to view the HSQL through its databasemanager tool. Based on your comment I understand you are doing other insert operations

Comment: Hi Acewin, Thanks for your reply. I resolved that issue, there is a trigger on that table which i didnt notice.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. The table had trigger on it which I didnt notice. Thanks for your input Acewin.